# Can Python optimize this simple variable call?

Tags: python, python-2.6

It seems like python (2.6) is not able to optimize this simple temp variable 'a' ?

I use to assign a local variable to some code in order to reduce the line length.

To me this is a simple optimization any correct compiler can do automatically.

```
from dis import dis

def f(func):
  func()

def functioncall():
  print ' => function called'

def unoptimized():
  print 'in unoptimized'
  a = functioncall
  f(func=a)

def optimized():
  print 'in optimized'
  f(func=functioncall)

unoptimized()
optimized()

print 'dis(unoptimized)'
dis(unoptimized)
print 'dis(optimized)'
dis(optimized)
```

Output :

```
in unoptimized
 => function called
in optimized
 => function called
dis(unoptimized)
 10           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('in unoptimized')
              3 PRINT_ITEM
              4 PRINT_NEWLINE

 11           5 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (functioncall)
              8 STORE_FAST               0 (a)

 12          11 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (f)
             14 LOAD_CONST               2 ('func')
             17 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             20 CALL_FUNCTION          256
             23 POP_TOP
             24 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             27 RETURN_VALUE
dis(optimized)
 15           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('in optimized')
              3 PRINT_ITEM
              4 PRINT_NEWLINE

 16           5 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (f)
              8 LOAD_CONST               2 ('func')
             11 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (functioncall)
             14 CALL_FUNCTION          256
             17 POP_TOP
             18 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             21 RETURN_VALUE
```

Why it cannot remove this automatically?

```
 11           5 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (functioncall)
              8 STORE_FAST               0 (a)
```

Answer (score 5):

CPython, the standard implementation of Python, doesn't do much optimization; it is a pretty straightforward translation of source code to bytecode. There are a few optimizations thrown in (elimination or hoisting of code under `if __debug__` being one of them) and I do believe there's a peephole optimizer of some kind, but I assume the compilation phase is meant to be reasonably quick, which precludes doing a lot of analysis.

Maintainability also seems key to the core Python developers. Here is [a thread from 2009](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/dev/755165) in which a patch for dead code removal is considered, then rejected, because it would make the compiler less maintainable.

If you want high performance, you want something other than CPython; maybe PyPy would help. Python in general is optimized to save programmer time, not runtime. If you don't want dead code in your bytecode, don't put it in your source code.  :-)

Comment: I could be wrong, but I thought that PyPy actually does do optimization like this, at the loss of C extensions.

Comment: You should put this back in: "If you don't want dead code in your bytecode, don't put it in your source code." :)

Comment: :-) Done, why not! I took it out because technically that's not dead code, it is in fact executed.

Answer (score 1):

In principle the Python interpreter could optimize this.

In practice, people program in Python because it is fast to write code in it, not because code written with it is fast. So in this particular case, the programmer is expected to to the optimization.

Answer (score 0):

In python, your source code does not entirely disappear - a `def` statement is an executable statement which creates a function object. You are asking why python doesn't cleverly do something other than what it was asked in the name of optimisation.

This sort of optimisation is easy enough to perform by hand, with the help of a lint tool if necessary. It's not worth introducing the kind of unexpected consequences that might accrue. After all, the point of python is to easy to read and write.

Comment: I don't agree wiyh you. This is a very simple optimization most compiler already do, why not do it? It's easy to detect, easy to implement.

Comment: @Gaetan Nowhere do I say that this is difficult. It's problematic.

Comment: Problematic doesn't mean it shouldn't be done. This is clearly a flow in the language. Most of the time, optimizing a code implies to made it less readable, I prefere knowing the situation in which the code will be optimized and thus write more readable code, than having to do some kung foo in my code. I pretty know well the C++ optimization and I'm so disapointed by the python interpreter on this matter. This, and the bad multithreading model on python

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: it's a feature.

I believe that this type of optimization should *not* be done *by default* because `y=g(f(x))` is *not* equivalent to `a=f(x) ; y=g(a)`: Python has side-effects which are here by design.

Local namespaces are designed to be accessed within Python itself: they have a clearly defined API.  The documentation of the `eval` function and the `exec` statement (Python >= 2.4) states that "If provided, locals can be any mapping object".

One possible application is to write a Python debugger in Python.  I can subclass `dict` so that each read/write in a local namespace triggers some GUI event; I am now able to observe the intermediate result `a` between `a=f(x)` and `y=g(a)`.  Without that possibility, I would have to inspect the CPython virtual stack, or whatever they use in any other Python implementation.

Besides debugging, I see other possible uses of this feature.  I could imagine embedding Python in a video game engine.  The designers in charge of the story, quests, characters, events, all that stuff, are here to convert their imagination into game content, not to write code.  To make their life easier, I could run their scripts with a special local namespace that comes with some pre-loaded and/or real-time values.
The names `my_hp` and `their_hp` would always return/set the current number of hitpoints of the two creatures involved in the "attack" event that triggered the script.  My designers would not need to type `self.` all the time (and they would not even know about classes and objects).  In a way, `my_hp` would act like a global or a descriptor, except that it would be local to a creature and would not require an explicit class/instance de-referencing.  This is MUCH easier to implement that way than trying to parse their script and guess when we have to add `self` in front of stuff.

In short: you never know what the virtual machine will do with your code, so things that may seem identical are not always so.